# Server SSL, routing and container management in a single management application

Tags: networking, web-server, web-hosting-control-panel, docker

As per the title: Server SSL, routing and container management in a single management application

Does something like this exist?

Typically I would manage this using AWS Certificate Manager, Application Load Balancer + Docker on EC2.

Or Let's Encrypt + nginx + Docker on any server hosting for something more manual.

Is there a service that that can do all this as a single application running on a server, and pull my container images from a repository somewhere?

I'm just looking to keep the cost of managing such a set up to a minimum.

Answer (score 2):

Answering myself as I've stumbled on a link a few days after looking for a solution on Hacker news. The product is https://coolify.io

Found here:

[So you moved off Heroku, where did you go?](https://archive.ph/t6Jxx)

Whether I will use this or not I don't know, I have since put together a GitHub actions workflow / AWS solution which is working well, but the author of this service deserves a link :)